# XSD specific elements in different position

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

The problem I faced to is to build correct XSD schema for my XML

I have the following XML:

```
<VanToRoute>
   <VanId>1111</VanId>
   <RouteNo>1459</RouteNo>
   <RouteNo>1458</RouteNo>
   <RouteNo>2459</RouteNo>
   <RouteNo>1THU</RouteNo>
</VanToRoute>
<VanToRoute>
   <RouteNo>2458</RouteNo>
   <VanId>2222</VanId>
   <RouteNo>1457</RouteNo>
   <RouteNo>1NEW</RouteNo>
   <RouteNo>2NEW</RouteNo>
</VanToRoute>
<VanToRoute>
   <RouteNo>1215</RouteNo>
   <RouteNo>2457</RouteNo>
   <VanId>2222</VanId>
</VanToRoute>
<VanToRoute>
   <VanId>4444</VanId>    
   <RouteNo>2456</RouteNo>
   <RouteNo>1100</RouteNo>
   <RouteNo>2465</RouteNo>
</VanToRoute>
```

So the key point is to have required field of VanId and Unbounded number of RouteNo.

The main challenge is to set required fields with allowed placement of XML elements.

What I've done so far:

```
 <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="VanToRoute">
      <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence> 
                <xs:choice> 
                     <xs:element minOccurs="1" name="VanId" type="xs:unsignedshort" /> 
                     <xs:element minOccurs="1" name="RouteNo" type="xs:string" /> 
                </xs:choice> 
                <xs:choice>
                      <xs:element minOccurs="1" name="RouteNo" type="xs:string" /> 
                      <xs:element minOccurs="1" name="VanId" type="xs:unsignedshort" /> 
                </xs:choice> 
                <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="RouteNo" type="xs:string" /> 
               </xs:sequence> 
           </xs:sequence> 
      </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

But this solution is not correct for several reasons:

1. It's allowed to have duplicated VanId which is not correct
2. It's doesn't give the flexible to put VanId at the end of my list.

My question is - if that even possible to somehow imitate logic I'd like to put into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in XSD 1.1 using `xs:all` with `minOccurs`/`maxOccurs` on the contained element particles.

In XSD 1.0 you can define the content model as

```
sequence
  RouteNo occurs 0 to many
  VanId
  RouteNo occurs 0 to many
```

but this allows zero RouteNo's. You can get around this with the content model

```
choice
  sequence
    RouteNo occurs 1 to many
    VanId
    RouteNo occurs 0 to many
or
  sequence
    RouteNo occurs 0 to many
    VanId
    RouteNo occurs 1 to many
```

Comment: Thank you, currenty I am working with .NET Core, and I am getting exception: version 1.1 is invalid. To my great surprise, I saw a lot of similar questions asked 10 years ago regarded compatibility .NET 4.5 with XML version 1.1 but I never saw any with .NET Core.

Comment: Microsoft stopped implementing new W3C XML standards years ago. To get the latest XML technologies you need to look to third parties.

Comment: Note, I think you are confusing XML 1.1 with XSD 1.1. They are quite different things. Though Microsoft has implemented neither of them.

Comment: Yes, I am reffering to XSD 1.1 I understand the difference, they are like the two parts of the same world.

Comment: XSD and XML are certainly part of the same world, but the new features in XSD 1.1 are quite orthogonal to the new features in XML 1.1, and neither is dependent on the other.